# Python select from database numeric format

Tags: python, postgresql, decimal, numeric

```
    kurzor_databaza.execute("SELECT c0,c3,c6,c9,c12,c15,c18,c21 FROM teplota_tuv WHERE datum=(%s);",(datetime_object,))
    rows=kurzor_databaza.fetchall()
    hodnoty_databaza={}

    for row in rows:
      hodnoty_databaza['DEN']={'c0':row[0],'c3':row[1],'c6':row[2],'c9':row[3],'c12':row[4],'c15':row[5],'c18':row[6]}
      print hodnoty_databaza
```

I need delete **Decimal('')** from result.

> When I run program This is result.
>
> {'DEN': {'c9': Decimal('23.625'), 'c18': Decimal('22.625'), 'c3':
> Decimal('19.312'), 'c12': Decimal('23.062'), 'c0': Decimal('20.687'),
> 'c6': Decimal('19.75'), 'c15': Decimal('21.875')}}

Problems is Unsupported numeric type python.I need delete **Decimal('')** from result. Colums c0-c21 is numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert them to float:

```
hodnoty_databaza['DEN'] = {x:float(y) for x,y in hodnoty_databaza['DEN'].items()}
print hodnoty_databaza['DEN']
# {'c9': 23.625, 'c18': 22.625, 'c3': 19.312, 'c12': 23.062, 'c0': 20.687, 'c6': 19.75, 'c15': 21.875}
```

You can read more about [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Thank you RaminNietzsche, It is Solutions